# eigenvalues of a first order differential operator on a manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I have the following, maybe naive question:

Given a smooth vector field $X$ on a smooth manifold $M$ with $\dim M \geq 1$.
Then this defines a linear operator
$$
 D: C^\infty(M,\mathbb C) \to C^\infty(M,\mathbb C) ; f \mapsto X.f\,.
$$
What I would like to know is: What is known about the eigenvalues of this linear map $D$ ?

It is clear to me that constant maps are always mapped to $0$, so $0$ is always an eigenvalue. It is also clear that if $X=0$, then $D=0$ and there is no other eigenvalue.

But assume, $X$ is not the constant $0$-vector field. Does this imply that $D$ has a complex non-zero eigenvalue ? Does this depend on whether $M$ is compact or not?

**EDIT:**
It looks to me as if $X$ being not constantly zero is not enough to conclude the existence of a non-zero eigenvalue.
Motivated by the comment of Ben Grossmann I looked at the real line $\mathbb R$ and the circle $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ and it seems that $X(x)=\cos^2(x)$ should be an example of a vector field where $D$ has only the eigenvalue $0$ -- if my calculus was correct.

So, maybe the correct question is:
**Assume that $X$ is everywhere non-zero, does this imply that we have a non-zero eigenvalue ?**

The comment of Ben Grossmann answeres this in the affirmative for $M=\mathbb R$ and I think a very similar argument should work for the circle $M=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. The comment of Eric solves this in the affirmative locally but it is not clear how the global geomety of $M$ comes into play here.

Comment: If you look first at a local setting, you can choose a chart such that the vectorfield looks constant in this chart. With this local representation, you can easily get eigenvalues to the local version of the differential operator. The question is, how that can give a global result.

Comment: It might help to focus on what this problem looks like in the case that $M = \Bbb R$. In that case, for a given continuous function $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, we're looking for values $\lambda \neq 0$ and functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that 
$$
g(x)f'(x) = \lambda f(x) \implies f(x) = C\exp\left[\lambda\int_0^x[g(t)]^{-1}dt\right]
$$
So, as log as the function $g$ associated with the vector field is everywhere non-zero, every $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @Eric: Thank you for this idea! Is there an easy reason why every vector field looks constant in a small chart? Is this a direct application of the Inverse Function Theorem or is it a more complicated argument?

Comment: @Cosine i am referring to this [Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightening_theorem_for_vector_fields).

Comment: @Eric: Thank you!

Comment: Another example: Take the Circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ and the vectorfield $X(\phi_0)= \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\big|_{\phi=\phi_0}$. Then solving for the functions $f$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\big|_{\phi=\phi_0}=\lambda f(\phi_0)$ with $\lambda\neq 0$, we only get solutions $f(\phi)=Ce^{\lambda\phi}$. This can only be a solution if $f(0)=f(2\pi)$, meaning either $C=0$, which doesn’t define an eigenfunction, or $1=e^{2\pi\lambda}$. This is possible if and only if $\lambda =ki$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Eric: Nice example, but I don't quite understand what it is supposed to show, since it does have non-zero eigenvalues, namely $\lambda=k i$ for $k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Cosine You are right (I started my comment before your edit, so I didn’t see the question changing)

Comment: @Eric: Sorry for the changing of question ... By the way, I just computed another example on $M=\mathbb{R}$. Take $X(x)=x$. If I am not mistaken, the set of eigenvalues should constist exactly of the non-negative integers $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @Cosine What do you mean by $X(x) = x$? Should that instead be $(X\cdot f)(x) = xf'(x)$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Yes, this is what I meant. I used the (maybe not very good) notation that since $\mathbb{R}$ has a canonical chart, a vector field on $\mathbb{R}$ "is" just a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. So maybe a better notation for what I mean would be $X(x)=x \frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: @Cosine It's an abuse of notation for sure, but that's fine as long as we're on the same page. And I agree with your result; for other eigenvalues, the only candidate for an eigenfunction, $f(x) = x^{\lambda}$, fails to either be defined or differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: It is worth noting, perhaps, that there are no other elements of the "spectrum" (in the sense of functional analysis) that are not eigenvalues. In particular, $X - \lambda \,\text{id}$ never fails to be surjective (whether or not it fails to be injective). In general, we find that
$$
((\lambda \,\text{id} + X)\cdot f)(x) = e^{-\lambda x} \frac d{dx}\left(e^{\lambda x} f(x)\right)
$$
so that for any $g$, $f(x) = e^{-\lambda x}\int_0^x e^{\lambda t}g(t)\,dt$ solves $((\lambda \text{id} + X)\cdot f) = g$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Are you referring to the example $X(x)=x\frac{d}{dx}$ or the general case $M=\mathbb{R}$ or the even more general case of an arbitrary manifold? Although I am interested in eigenvalues, more general knowledge about the spectrum sounds intersesting as well ...

Comment: I was referring to your example, but I realize now that I made a mistake. Really, the comment deals with the constant vector field $X = 1$, which is to say $X = \frac d{dx}$

Comment: @BenGrossmann: But for the constant vector field, every (complex) number is an eigenvalue, so the spectrum consists of eigenvalues only, right?

Comment: @Cosine that's right

Comment: There is a similar trick that could potentially applied in your case, since 
$$
((\lambda \text{id} + X) \cdot f)(x) = x^{1-\lambda} \frac d{dx}\left(x^{\lambda} f(x)\right),
$$
but I don't think that reversing this process necessarily yields a smooth function

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez : Now I finally got to go through your idea. Unfortunately, I think it does not work. Take on the torus R^2/Z^2 a constant vector field w=(a,b)in R^2 with a/b irrational. Then I think the funtion f(x,y)=exp(2pi i x) is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue 2pi i a which is non-zero .